# How Can I count an SQL Row and store it in a variable using FLASK without always getting 1 as an answer?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

So I have the following code

```
from dbconnect import connection

def propertyCount():
    c, conn = connection()
    property_count = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties")

return int(property_count)
```

In this code using python and Flask I am importing connection,

Then I defined a new function which should do the following:

Connect to the database and get the count of rows in the specific table called "properties" and then store it in a variable named $property_count, and return the value of that variable to be called in jinja later on.

The current problem is that it is always returning 1 as a value when tested in a web browser but when I use the code in SQL Only (phpmyadmin) it is returning the proper amount of rows.

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute()` would output you the *number of affected rows*, not the results of the query. To get the result, use `.fetchone()`:

```
from dbconnect import connection

def propertyCount():
    c, conn = connection()
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties")
    property_count = c.fetchone()[0]

    return property_count
```

Also note how the `return` is indented (though I think it was just a question posting typo).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help alecxe , worked as a charm ;) yes the return was a minor typo. I'm a newbie to python and still trying some stuff out. Thanks again